# Consulta FULL OUTER JOIN con 4 tablas en postgresl

Tags: postgresql, sql

Hola tengo las siguientes tablas

Tabla **productos**, **ingresos_mercancias**, **facturas_detalles** y **facturas_cabeceras**

Script de **productos**

```
CREATE TABLE productos
(
id serial NOT NULL,
codigo_barras character varying,
descripcion character varying(100),
stock_minimo double precision,
id_proveedor integer,
stock_ideal double precision,
unidad character varying,
CONSTRAINT clave_primaria PRIMARY KEY (id),
CONSTRAINT fk_provee FOREIGN KEY (id_proveedor)  REFERENCES contactos (id),
CONSTRAINT productos_codigo_barras_key UNIQUE (codigo_barras)
)
```

Script de **ingresos_mercancias**

```
CREATE TABLE ingresos
(
id serial NOT NULL,
id_producto integer,
fecha date,
hora character varying(8),
cantidad double precision,
tipo integer,
CONSTRAINT pk_ingresos PRIMARY KEY (id),
CONSTRAINT fk_producto FOREIGN KEY (id_producto) REFERENCES productos (id)
)
```

Script de **facturas_detalles**

```
CREATE TABLE salidas
(
id serial NOT NULL,
id_producto integer,
id_cabecera integer,
cantidad double precision,
CONSTRAINT pkfacturadetalle PRIMARY KEY (id),
CONSTRAINT fkproducto FOREIGN KEY (id_producto) REFERENCES productos (id), 
CONSTRAINT fkcabecera FOREIGN KEY (id_cabecera) REFERENCES facturas_cabeceras(id) 
)
```

Script de **facturas_cabeceras**

```
CREATE TABLE facturas_cabeceras
(
id serial NOT NULL,
codigo character varying(200),
fecha date,
estado character(1),
hora character varying(8),
tipo_factura character varying(100),
CONSTRAINT pkfacturacabecera PRIMARY KEY (id), 
)
```

Lo que necesito hacer es una consulta la cual me devuelva la cantidad de ingresos y salidas que tiene cada producto y me de la diferencia entre ambas teniendo en cuenta un rango de fechas y el saldo anterior a la fecha inicial por ejemplo

quiero saber el balance de productos entre 1 de enero y 31 de enero pero
 el resultado debería mostrarse así

```
id | decripcion | saldo_anterior | ingresos | salidas | saldo
-------------------------------------------------------------
1  | producto1  | 20             | 35       |  12     | 43
2  | producto2  | 5              | 7        |  10     | 2
3  | producto3  | 100            | 70       |  95     | 75
```

donde

- id y descripcion pertenecen a productos
- saldo_anterior es la diferencia de todos los ingresos y salidas del producto antes de la fecha inicial (o sea del 31 de diciembre hacia atrás)
- ingresos son todos los ingresos entre el rango de fechas 1 de enero a 31 de enero
- salidas son todas las salidas (facturas_detalles) entre el rango de fechas 1 de enero a 31 de enero (la fecha esta en facturas_cabeceras)
- saldo es igual a **saldo_anterior + ingresos - salidas**

ya estuve intentando de varias maneras pero me da error

esta es la consulta que he estado usando

```
with 
ingresos as (
select id_producto, max(p.descripcion) as descripcion, max(p.codigo_barras) as codigo, sum(cantidad) as cantidad from ingresos i, productos p 
where i.id_producto=p.id and fecha between '2019-01-01' and '2019-01-31' group by id_producto
salidas as (
select id_producto, max(p.descripcion) as descripcion, max(p.codigo_barras) as codigo, sum(cantidad) as cantidad from salidas s, productos p 
where s.id_producto=p.id and s.fecha between '2019-01-01' and '2019-01-31' group by id_producto
select 
coalesce(s.id_producto, i.id_producto) as id_producto, coalesce(i.descripcion,s.descripcion) as descripcion, coalesce(i.codigo,s.codigo) as codigo, 
select coalesce(sum(cantidad),0) from ingresos where fecha < '2019-01-01' and id_producto= coalesce(s.id_producto, i.id_producto))-
select coalesce(sum(cantidad),0) from salidas s where  fecha < '2019-01-01' and id_producto= coalesce(s.id_producto, i.id_producto))) as saldo_anterior,
s.cantidad as salidas, i.cantidad as ingresos, 
select coalesce(sum(cantidad),0) from ingresos where fecha < '2019-01-01' and id_producto= coalesce(s.id_producto, i.id_producto))-
select coalesce(sum(cantidad),0) from salidas s where fecha < '2019-01-01' and id_producto= coalesce(s.id_producto, i.id_producto))) + coalesce(i.cantidad,0) - coalesce(s.cantidad,0)) as saldo 
from salidas as s full outer join ingresos as i on s.id_producto = i.id_producto
```

pero me da error porque cuando hago una consulta por ejemplo del 2 de enero entonces me aparece en blanco, he pensado que si hago un full outer join con las 4 tablas me pueda funcionar y ahí es donde pido ayuda, muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola, podrias compartir los INSERT de las tablas para realizar pruebas. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola despues de mucho intentar lo logre de la siguiente manera

```
with ingresos as (
select i.id_producto, max(p.descripcion) as descripcion, max(p.codigo_barras) as codigo, coalesce(sum(i.cantidad),0) as cantidad from ingresos_mercancias i, productos p 
where i.id_producto=p.id and fecha between '2019-01-01' and '2019-01-31' group by id_producto order by id_producto
),
ingresos_anteriores as (
select i.id_producto, max(p.descripcion) as descripcion, max(p.codigo_barras) as codigo, coalesce(sum(i.cantidad),0) as cantidad from ingresos_mercancias i, productos p 
where i.id_producto=p.id and fecha<'2019-01-01' group by id_producto order by id_producto
),
salidas as (
select id_producto, max(p.descripcion) as descripcion, max(p.codigo_barras) as codigo, coalesce(sum(cantidad),0) as cantidad from facturas_detalles as fd, facturas_cabeceras fc, productos p 
where fd.id_cabecera=fc.id and fd.id_producto=p.id and fc.fecha between '2019-01-01' and '2019-01-31' group by id_producto
),
salidas_anteriores as (
select id_producto, max(p.descripcion) as descripcion, max(p.codigo_barras) as codigo, coalesce(sum(cantidad),0) as cantidad from facturas_detalles as fd, facturas_cabeceras fc, productos p 
where fd.id_cabecera=fc.id and fd.id_producto=p.id and fc.fecha<'2019-01-01' group by id_producto
)

select 
coalesce(i.id_producto,ia.id_producto,s.id_producto,sa.id_producto) as id_producto, 
coalesce(i.codigo,ia.codigo,s.codigo,sa.codigo) as codigo, 
coalesce(i.descripcion,ia.descripcion,s.descripcion,sa.descripcion) as descripcion, 
sum(coalesce(ia.cantidad,0) - coalesce(sa.cantidad,0)) as saldo_anterior,
sum(coalesce(i.cantidad,0)) as ingresos, sum(coalesce(s.cantidad,0)) as salidas,
sum((coalesce(ia.cantidad,0) - coalesce(sa.cantidad,0)) + coalesce(i.cantidad,0) - coalesce(s.cantidad,0)) as saldo

from 

ingresos as i
full outer join ingresos_anteriores as ia on i.id_producto=ia.id_producto
full outer join salidas as s on s.id_producto=i.id_producto 
full outer join salidas_anteriores as sa on sa.id_producto=ia.id_producto 
group by coalesce(i.id_producto,ia.id_producto,s.id_producto,sa.id_producto),coalesce(i.codigo,ia.codigo,s.codigo,sa.codigo),coalesce(i.descripcion,ia.descripcion,s.descripcion,sa.descripcion)
order by coalesce(i.descripcion,ia.descripcion,s.descripcion,sa.descripcion)
```

Espero le pueda servir a alguien mas o si hay algún error, agradecería me lo hicieran saber